# Regular expression question (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

How do I write a regular expression to match (_Rev. n.nn) in the following filenames (where n is a number):

- Filename_Rev. 1.00
- Filename_Rev. 1.10

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information. What are you trying to extract? Just the number? If so, do you want it as a single number or its constituent parts?

Comment: I want to extract "_Rev. n.nn".

Comment: I need to know if the filename ends with "_Rev. n.nn" and then I can extract the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should capture versions >9
Edit: Fixed

```
string captureString = "abc123butts_Rev. 1.00";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(.(?!_Rev))+\w_Rev\. (?<version>\d+\.\d+)");
string version = reg.Match(captureString).Groups["version"].Value;
```

Comment: This looks promising but it's not compiling. Could u run it please? Please note "Filename" could be anything but "Rev. n.nn" must be at the end of the filename (excluding the extension). Thanks

Comment: "_Rev. n.nn" I meant to write.

Comment: Wait is there a file extension after _Rev.?

Comment: No. I took it out with Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension().

Comment: Ok, then this should suit your needs.

Comment: Oooo, I like the named group, that's a nice touch I had forgotten about in .NET regexs

Comment: @FlyingStreudel, what is that negative lookahead for?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (for the whole line):

```
@"^Filename_Rev\.\s\d\.\d\d$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @leppie's answer (give him the green check not me), you can extract the numbers from your regex match by putting parens around the `\d`'s.

```
Regex foo = new Regex(@"_Rev\.\s(\d)\.(\d\d)$");
GroupCollection groups = foo.Match("Filename_Rev. 1.00").Groups;
string majorNum = groups[1].Value;
string minorNum = groups[2].Value;
System.Console.WriteLine(majorNum);
System.Console.WriteLine(minorNum);
```

Comment: Leppies answer does not support any filename nor two digit major versions. Just sayin'

Comment: yeah, fixed the filename bit... But I don't feel like there's enough info about weather or not 2 digit major nums are needed from the OP.

Comment: Thanks Martin but I have to give it to FlyingStreudel.

Comment: yes, arrays are 0-based but the first group matches the entire matched string here, so the [1] and [2] Do give the correct groups.